# Azure SQL Server Rest API access

Tags: c#, .net, rest, azure, https

I'm trying to get some info about my DB from MS Azure via REST API (it's only testing my knowledge about REST). Using C#. But where I need to put login and password for DB? or needn't ? I have 403 http error every time.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://management.core.windows.net:8443/{subscriptionId}/services/sqlservers/servers/{servername}/databases/testDB");
       request.Method = "GET";
       request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2012-03-01");
       WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
       Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
       StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
       String res = reader.ReadToEnd();
       Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST API operations you're trying to perform are part of [`Azure Service Management API`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx) and they work on a different authentication mechanism. You would either need to provide a X509 based Management Certificate or use Azure AD token for authentication purposes. For more details on authenticating these API requests, please see this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx.